# What can i do against cobblestone getting stuck in my recycler output?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft, minecraft-industrialcraft

I have a recycler that gets fed cobblestone to the top by buildcraft pipes. Directly adjacent, i put an automatic crafting table to produce scrap boxes. However, sometimes the cobblestone gets fed in the output slot of the recycler. I think it happens when a cobblestone comes in during the operation?! Can anyone give me a tip how i can avoid this problem? Would putting a chest on top of the recycler work?

Comment: Have you tried putting the pipe on the side. This always works for my.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i figured it out. I accidentally had one of the pipes connected to the side, and cobblestone would get input in the output slot (although this can't be done manually, feels buggy to me). I changed the pipes to avoid that, and it solved the problem.